# Is there a way to change the type of a property at a specific path in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given an interface A, how can I make a Generic Type that is given the interface and a string literal union of paths and returns another interface with the fields at the given paths transformed into another type ?

e.g.

Given the interface:

```js
interface Input {
 user: {
  fullname: string;
  birthdate: Date;
 }
}
```

how can I make a Generic Type such that:

```js
TurnDateToNumber<User, 'user.birthdate'>
```

returns the following:

```js
interface Input {
 user: {
  fullname: string;
  birthdate: number;
 }
}
```

Comment: This sort of deeply nested type manipulation tends to have a zillion edge cases (e.g., what to do with optional properties, unions, intersections, index signatures, etc) so it's important that any proposed solution be tested against your use cases, and that you clarify any possible ambiguity by providing input/output requirements.  For example, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Na1d9N) meet your needs?  Test carefully before answering.  If it works I'd be happy to write up an answer but that usually takes a while and I don't want to spend that time unless I know it's suitable.

Comment: You can check also [my article](https://catchts.com/deep-pick)